# Rails number of weeks in month

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

How can I in rails calculate the number of weeks in a given month?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i dont know exactly what you want... But maybe you want something like this:

`(Time::days_in_month(05,2010).to_f / 7)`

`#> 4.42857142857143`

Comment: Hi Michael, I want to calculate how many weeks there is in January, February etc...

Comment: from sunday till monday? Because otherwise it would be always 4. 28/7 is 4. 30/7 = 4.29 etc

Comment: Dont understand, some moths have 5 weeks and others 4 right? Cant I calculate that?

Comment: the maximum number of days of a month is 31. 31/7 = 4.43 weeks. So it is impossible to have 5 full weeks in a month.

Comment: Ok stupid me! But is there a way to find out how many weeks is in a given month?

Comment: The calculation he gave you above is exactly that. There is no `weeks_in_month` method so you have to use the days and times them by 7 (how many days in a week.) Just swap 05 for your month, and 2010 for your year.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to know how many weeks including partial weeks there were in a month.  Think of it like rows in a calendar.  How many rows do you need?  You have to consider the number of days and also what day the month starts on.  October 2011 actually has 6 unique weeks for example.

This is my answer (@date is the current date):

```
@week_count = (0.5 + (@date.at_end_of_month.day + @date.at_beginning_of_month.wday).to_f / 7.0).round
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following methods:

```
  WEEK_NUMBER_FORMAT = '%W'

  # Returns the first day of month.
  # If invoked without any arguments, this would return the
  # first day of current month
  def first_day_of_month(date_time=Time.now)
    date_time.beginning_of_month
  end

  # Returns the last day of month.
  # If invoked without any arguments, this would return the
  # last day of current month
  def last_day_of_month(date_time=Time.now)
    date_time.end_of_month
  end

  # Returns the week number in the year in which the specified date_time lies.
  # If invoked without any arguments, this would return the
  # the week number in the current year
  def week_number(date_time=Time.now)
    date_time.strftime(WEEK_NUMBER_FORMAT).to_i
  end

  # Returns the number of weeks in the month in which the specified date_time lies.
  # If invoked without any arguments, this would return the
  # the number of weeks in the current month
  def weeks_in_month(date_time=Time.now)
    week_number(last_day_of_month(date_time)) - week_number(first_day_of_month(date_time))  + 1
  end
```

Usage: weeks_in_month(date_time)

Hope it helps:

Thanks,

Jignesh

Answer (score 2):

```
def number_of_weeks_in_month
  4
end
```

Comment: upvoted for sarcasm that made me lol

Answer (score 0):

Use the gem [week_of_month](https://github.com/sachin87/week-of-month)

```
d = Date.new(2012,1,1)

d.total_weeks

=> 5
```

Comment: This is so easy as `(from..to).each_slice(7).to_a.size`. Which is how's stated in your gem repository. Adding an answer like this looks just like promoting a repository of your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
def number_of_weeks_month(start_of_month, count, end_of_month)
 if start_date > end_of_month
  return count
 else
  number_of_weeks_month(start_date.end_of_week + 1, count + 1, end_of_month)
 end
end
```

get number of weeks for month like this

```
number_of_weeks_month(Date.parse("2017-11-01"),0,Date.parse("2017-11-30"))
```

this return 4

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.today.end_of_month.day/7
=> 4
```