# Get calendar week numbers in requested month in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, week-number

I've been searching for hours now and I just can't find the right answer.
Hope you can help me out.

Ruby:    `1.9.3p194`
Rails:    `3.2.8`

#### Goal:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > get_weeknumbers_in_month 1, 2012
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
1.9.3p194 :002 > get_weeknumbers_in_month 2, 2012
=> [5, 6, 7, 8]
1.9.3p194 :003 > get_weeknumbers_in_month 3, 2012
=> [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
1.9.3p194 :004 > get_weeknumbers_in_month 4, 2012
=> [14, 15, 16, 17]
```

So, I actually want an array of calendar week numbers when the method `get_weeknumbers_in_month` is called.

#### Research:

To get the month numbers from a date:

```
DateTime.parse("2012-01-10").month
=> 1
```

To get the number of days in a month:

```
Time::days_in_month(1, 2012)
=> 31
```

To get the calendar week number of a date:

```
DateTime.parse("2012-04-12").strftime("%W").to_i
=> 15
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails number of weeks in month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911045/rails-number-of-weeks-in-month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you've almost done!
the last is to calculate first and last dates for month, isn't it?
So something like next may work (not tested)

```
def get_weeknumbers_in_month(month, year)
  first_week_num = Date.new(year,month,1).strftime("%U").to_i
  last_week_num = Date.new(year,month,1).end_of_month.strftime("%U").to_i
  (first_week_num..last_week_num).to_a
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I really was close indeed :o 
Only, now a month can return 6 week numbers. right?
And, when looking at Sun, January 1st. This will be in week 52, so the array will be left empty.
`a = (52..3).to_a  #=> []`
So, now it's only a matter of filtering this out and push the numbers in the correct order.
`if start_of_month_in_week == 0 && end_of_month_in_week != 0; weeks.push(52); weeks.push (1..end_of_month_in_week).to_a`

Comment: I know, I was editing my comment because of an [enter] instead of a [shift]+[enter] ;-)

Comment: mmm, I didn't get situation about empty result. how can I reproduce it ?

Comment: `irb :001 > a = (52..3).to_a  
 #=> [] `

Comment: actually, I'm still confused about how the first day of any month can get you 52th week number)

Comment: Ah, well, 01-01-2012 is on the Sunday of week 52, 2011.

Comment: this way? `1.9.3p125 :021 > DateTime.parse("2012-01-01").strftime("%W").to_i
   => 0 
   1.9.3p125 :022 > DateTime.parse("2012-01-01").strftime("%U").to_i
   => 1 `

Comment: Indeed, when the starting day is in week 52 of the previous year it'll return zero.